# Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 1 is crashing constantly while gradle is building

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

While building gradle, Android Studio flamingo constantly freezes and then crashes unexpectedly without any warning, this happens specially when working on UI heavy tasks. The crashes started when I updated my Android Studio to Flamingo.

**Here's the Android Studio specifications**

```
Build: AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841, 202304191751, 

AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841, JRE 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694x64 JetBrains s.r.o., OS Linux(amd64) v5.19.0-45-generic, screens 1920.0x1080.0, 1920.0x1080.0

AS: Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1
Kotlin plugin: 222-1.8.20-release-AS3739.54
Android Gradle Plugin: 8.0.1
Gradle: 8.0
Gradle JDK: JetBrains Runtime version 17.0.6
NDK: from local.properties: (not specified), latest from SDK: (not found)
CMake: from local.properties: (not specified), latest from SDK: (not found), from PATH: (not found)
```

**Here's my gradle.wrapper.properties file:**

```
## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
#Mon Jul 03 16:27:15 IST 2023
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
android.useAndroidX=true
kotlin.code.style=official
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx1536M" -Dfile.encoding\=UTF-8
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=true
```

**System Specifications of the running system**

```
Hardware Model : Dell Inc. Inspiron 15 5510
Processor : 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-11390H @ 3.40GHz × 8
Memory : 16.0 GiB
Graphics : Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
Disk Capacity : 512.1 GB
OS Name : Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
OS Type : 64-bit
GNOME Version : 42.5
Windowing System : Wayland
```

Increasing, descreasing IDE heap size and gradle daemon heap size didn't do anything. The IDE freezes while gradle is building and then crashes.

Comment: same this is happening to me, gradle is crashing while building the app.

Comment: Consider reporting the issue to Google via Help -> Submit Feedback. It's hard to tell why the IDE is crashing without even seeing the stacktrace.

Comment: maybe update to patch 2?

Comment: Try reinstalling android studio